# How do I run a class concurrently in my main function?

Tags: python, class, concurrent.futures

I want to call and run a class in my `main()` function concurrently.
I have different methods in my code that I want to run at the same time using `concurrent.futures` and I figured out I could put them in a `class` instead.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import requests
import time
import concurrent.futures

img_urls = [
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516117172878-fd2c41f4a759',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532009324734-20a7a5813719',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524429656589-6633a470097c',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530224264768-7ff8c1789d79'
]

t1 = time.perf_counter()


class Download:
    def __init__(self, img_url):
        self.img_url = img_url

    def download_image(self, img_url):
        img_bytes = requests.get(self.img_url).content
        return img_bytes

    def image_name(self, img_bytes):
        img_bytes = download_image(self, img_url)
        img_name = self.img_url.split('/')[3]
        img_name = f'{img_name}.jpg'
        with open(img_name, 'wb') as img_file:
            img_file.write(img_bytes)
            print(f'{img_name} was downloaded...')

    def run(self):
        download_image(self, img_url)
        image_name(self, img_bytes)


def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(Download, img_urls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

t2 = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')
```

Comment: Mapping `Download` just calls the `__init__` method, not any of the others. You need to write a function that calls all the methods that you want, and map that.

Comment: You don't run a class, a class is a collection of methods. You run the methods.

Comment: Create an instance of download class and then you can call the methods within it. You can't call a class. Your error log should mention that as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's particularly good practice but you could have the `__init__` method call the other methods so you have a 'self-running' class that executes methods as soon as it is instantiated.

Comment: But how do I run those methods at the same time using `concurrent.futures`? Also I updated the code to add a function that runs all the methods.

Comment: @SimonN What do you suggest? I have some methods that need to be run at the same time, one of them takes `img_url` as a value and they all dependant on each other.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to execute the run function of different `Download` objects concurrently.

The first thing is that there is a syntax error in the run function, it should be:

```py
def run(self):
    img_bytes = download_image(self, img_url)
    image_name(self, img_bytes)
```

otherwise `img_bytes` isn't defined.

Then you need to pass the correct callable to the executor. If you pass the class Download, it will only create an instance of it, not actually call the run method; to do so with every time a new instance of Download something like this should work:

```py
executor.map(lambda url: Download(url).run, img_urls)
```

Comment: Do you think this is a good practice or you suggest a different approach to solve such problem?

Comment: @Lukas I think it is an ok approach; I don't see any particular issue

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is as Marco mentioned.

As you want to call and run using class, you can call the multithreading code from the `__init__` function.

```
import requests
import time
import concurrent.futures

img_urls = [
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516117172878-fd2c41f4a759",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532009324734-20a7a5813719",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524429656589-6633a470097c",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530224264768-7ff8c1789d79",
]

t1 = time.perf_counter()


class Download:
    def __init__(self, img_url):
        self.img_url = img_url
        self.download_all_images()

    def download_image(self, img_url):
        img_bytes = requests.get(img_url, stream=True).content
        return img_bytes

    def image_name(self, img_url):
        try:
            img_bytes = self.download_image(img_url)
            img_name = img_url.split("/")[3]
            img_name = f"{img_name}.jpg"
            print("here", img_name)
            with open(img_name, "wb") as img_file:
                img_file.write(img_bytes)
                print(f"{img_name} was downloaded...")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def download_all_images(self):
        try:
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                executor.map(self.image_name, self.img_url)
            return "Success"
        except:
            return "Failed"


def main():
    response = Download(img_urls)
    print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

t2 = time.perf_counter()

print(f"Finished in {t2 - t1} seconds")
```